# Rails: Sum only once per particular column combination

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by, distinct

I have this kind of table:

```
dated       category_id  policy_id  available
2016-01-01  1            1          5
2016-01-01  1            2          5
2016-01-01  2            1          2
2016-01-02  1            1          4
2016-01-03  1            1          3
2016-01-03  2            1          3
2016-01-03  2            2          3
```

I want to show the availability (each category added) for each date, independent of the policy. The results in this case should be:

```
2016-01-01 => 7
2016-01-02 => 4
2016-01-03 => 6
```

I am using the *groupdate* gem which allows queries like this:

```
Item.group_by_day(:dated).sum(:available)
```

This query of course returns *12* (should be *7*) for the first date and *9* (should be *6*) for the last.
**How can I use only one date/category-combination?** I tried `.uniq(:category_id)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is harder than it should be, because your data isn't properly normalized.  Policy & availability should be in a separate model/DB table.

Comment: I updated the question. Category and policy are seperate models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this database subquery…

```
subquery = Item.select('DISTINCT ON(items.dated, items.category_id) items.id').order(:dated, :category_id).to_sql
```

…and then using Rails group_by like so

```
  available_by_date = items
      .where("items.id in (#{subquery})")
      .group_by_day(:dated)
      .sum(:available)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to figure out which value you want.  I could speculate that it is one of these:

```
Item.group_by_day(:available).average(:available)

Item.group_by_day(:available).max(:available)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just noticed that I simplified my example too much. I updated the question with the policy column. :)

Comment: @Railsana . . . This is easy to do in SQL, but I don't know how to do it in RonR.

Comment: **DISTINCT ON** seems to be the solution, but I cannot figure out how to do this in RoR either...

Comment: Does where not work ? something like `Item.where(category_id: @value).group_by_day(:dated).sum(:available)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
Item.group(["dated", "category_id"]).sum(:available)
```